# Custom numpy function with reduce capabilities

Tags: numpy, sympy

I am trying to create a function which can reduce an array which contains `sympy` `Symbol` objects. Elementwise functions and reduction over 1 axis seems to work:

```
from sympy import symarray, Max
import numpy as np

a = symarray('a', (3,3))
f = np.frompyfunc(lambda x,y: Max(x,y), 2, 1)

f.reduce(a, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([Max(a_0_0, a_1_0, a_2_0), Max(a_0_1, a_1_1, a_2_1),
       Max(a_0_2, a_1_2, a_2_2)], dtype=object)
```

But I cannot specify more than one axis:

```
f.reduce(a, axis=(0,1))
```

Output:

```
ValueError: reduction operation '<lambda> (vectorized)' is not reorderable, so at most one axis may be specified
```

Ofcourse, I could do something like `f.reduce(f.reduce(a, axis=0), axis=0)`, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way of doing it and things like `keepdims=True` does not work without explicit reshaping.

Comment: Can't you just reshape (and transpose if needed) `a` so you only need to reduce on 1 dimension?  As the error tells us, this custom `ufunc` can't do everything that a builtin one like `np.add` can do.  Considering the `frompyfunc` is more of a convenience than a speed tool, I don't consider that a great loss.

Comment: Yes, I could reshape the array beforehand, but it seems a bit complex to make it a general solution. for example an array with the shape ```(1,2,3,4)``` and I want to reduce ```axis=(1,3)``` - how would I go about this? First transpose the axes by ```(0,2,1,3)```, then reshape to ```(1,3,-1)``` and finally do the reduction over the last axis. Maybe this is the best alternative, but it feels a bit impractical...

Comment: Inconveniet maybe, but impractical or inefficient, no.  Allowing multiple axes for other ufunc, is, memory is correct, a relatively recent addition.  `ufunc.reduce` has this note 'For operations which are either not commutative or not associative, doing a reduction over multiple axes is not well-defined. '

Comment: I ended up using [```np.nditer```](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html#numpy-nditer) with ```op_axes``` and ```reduce_ok``` flag inspired by https://gist.github.com/seberg/5236560. It's still hacky though, the best solution would be if it was possible to define the (commutative/associative) property for an arbitrary function.